# How do I Statically Link SDL in VSCode with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, static-linking

The problem:
My Code is always compiling using a dynamic linker.

The setup:
I used `SDL2-devel-2.28.2-VC.zip`, because I use the MSVC compiler (64bit) with VSCode. To build my projects I use the .vscode folder with the following arguments for my SDL project.

> My task.json script:
>
> ```json
> {
>     "tasks": [
>         {
>             "type": "cppbuild",
>             "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
>             "command": "cl.exe",
>             "args": [
>                 "/Zi",
>                 "/EHsc",
>                 "/nologo",
>                 "/Fe${workspaceFolder}\\out\\Program.exe",
>                 "/Fo${workspaceFolder}\\obj\\",
>                 "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\*.cpp",
>
>                 "/IC:/dev/SDL2/include",
>                 "/link",
>                 "/LIBPATH:C:\\dev\\SDL2\\lib\\x64",
>                 "SDL2.lib",
>                 "SDL2main.lib"
>             ],
>             "options": {
>                 "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
>             },
>             "problemMatcher": [
>                 "$msCompile"
>             ],
>             "group": {
>                 "kind": "build",
>                 "isDefault": true
>             },
>             "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
>         }
>     ],
>     "version": "2.0.0"
> }
> ```

> My c_cpp_properties.json
>
> ```json
> {
>     "configurations": [
>         {
>             "name": "Win64",
>             "includePath": [
>                 "${workspaceFolder}/**",
>                 "C:/dev/SDL2/include"
>             ],
>             "defines": [
>                 "_DEBUG",
>                 "UNICODE",
>                 "_UNICODE"
>             ],
>             "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
>             "compilerPath": "cl.exe",
>             "cStandard": "c17",
>             "cppStandard": "c++17",
>             "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
>         }
>     ],
>     "version": 4
> }
> ```

I tried using the `/MT` flag in *task.json* - Nothing different happened

I tried using `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` in *c_cppproperties.json* like this: 
`"defines": ["SDL_MAIN_HANDLED"]` - Nothing different happened

With *Nothing different happened* I mean everything compiled fine, tho with dynamic linking.

I looked everywhere on the internet, I found nothing for VSCode with the MSVC Compiler.
I read through the entire documentation of SDL2, but found nothing usefull.

It always needed the SDL2.dll file to run. If not available, the program crashes with the log:
The execution of the code can't be proceeded, because SDL2.dll couldn't be found

Comment: `SDL2-devel-2.28.2-VC.zip` only contains a dynamic link binary of the library, you have to build a static one from source with cmake.

Comment: The `.lib` files in that download are not static libraries. They are import libraries that require a dll at runtime.

Comment: ***The execution of the code can't be proceeded, because SDL2.dll couldn't be found*** My advice is to just use the dlls and create an installer for your application that properly installs it and its required dlls like almost all commercial software does. It's not that hard to create a NSIS based installer or use WIX.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Thanks a lot for you help :) I will start looking into it!

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks a lot for your help too, :D as I said, I will start looking into it!